# XML to JSON to Dynamic object, get element property

Tags: json, xml, serialization, dynamic

I have am passed some xml:

```
<response>
  <SessionId>aaaaaaaaa</SessionId>
  <EventType>ProductList</EventType>
  <data>
    <Provider Name="Some Provider Name Here">
    <Id>166</Id>
    </Provider>
  </data>
</response>
```

i then convert it to a dynamic object:

```
dynamic responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(XDocument.Parse(response)));
```

after which i end up with this dynamic object:

```
{[response, {
  "SessionId": "aaaaaaaaa",
  "EventType": "ProductList",
  "data": {
    "Provider": [
      {
        "@Name": "Some Provider Name Here",
        "Id": "166",
        ...
```

I can now use the following `foreach` loop to access the properties:

```
foreach (var provider in responseObj.response.data.Provider)
{
    Console.WriteLine(provider.Id);
}
```

This all works fine.

**My Question:** How do i access the @Name attribute within my loop? cause using: `provider.Name` yields null and `provider.@Name` does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
provider["@Name"]
```

I think XPath can do the same in more convenient way.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(s);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//response/data/Provider/@Name");
```